# How to search object with the smallest value?

Tags: javascript

I have an array which contains a list of objects:

```js
let intervals = 
    [
       { id: "1", interval_start: "0", interval_end: "40" },
       { id: "2", interval_start: "41", interval_end: "65" },
       { id: "3", interval_start: "66", interval_end: "80" },
       { id: "4", interval_start: "81", interval_end: "100" },
    ];
    
var result = intervals.reduce(function(prev, current) {
  return (prev.interval_end > current.interval_end) ? prev : current
});

console.log(result)
```

I tried to search the object with the smallest `interval_end` which is `id: 1`

But this will return `id: 3`

Comment: this question is target of strange comment in chat, which is a shame.

Comment: @NinaScholz I don't know what to say to you, yesterday they attacked me saying that the question was unclear, but you and others understood it. I gave an example, an explanation, but others have argued that the smallest interval was not what I meant. Unfortunately on this world there is always one who gets up in the morning and decides to ruin your day, but honestly I don't care, thanks to you I solved the problem. Thank you again Nina and have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take smaller than as condition and the numerical value, because you would compare strings., which goes wrong for `'40'` and `'100'`, for example.

```js
let intervals = [
        { id: "1", interval_start: "0", interval_end: "40" },
        { id: "2", interval_start: "41", interval_end: "65" },
        { id: "3", interval_start: "66", interval_end: "80" },
        { id: "4", interval_start: "81", interval_end: "100" }
    ],
    result = intervals.reduce((prev, current) =>
        +prev.interval_end < +current.interval_end ? prev : current
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be in string comparison

```js
let intervals = 
[
   { id: "1", interval_start: "0", interval_end: "40" },
   { id: "2", interval_start: "41", interval_end: "65" },
   { id: "3", interval_start: "66", interval_end: "80" },
   { id: "4", interval_start: "81", interval_end: "100" },
];

console.log(intervals.reduce((prev, current) => parseInt(prev.interval_end) < parseInt(current.interval_end) ? prev : current, {}))
```